# what can I do, I want the data of the firebase is read by everyone but data delete by same auth id person

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is my Firebase Realtime Database Rule, suppose that here is two device user A and B , A adds data through App to firebase realTime Database , So B reads that data which is added by user A, Same B adds data through app , So A reads That Data, but both the user A or B delete only own Data which he has entered , A deletes only own data and B deletes only own data, but both user read data each other(means the data is entered by the user is visible to the world).. So which rule is apply here. 
for Ex- a comment section on facebook , the comment is visible to everyone but that comment is delete by admin or the persom who make that comment , so I want like this ,here is my databae rule code

```
 {
      "rules": {
        "$uid": {
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".read": "auth != null"
       }
     }
}
```

this is setup the firebase and firebaseUser and the child is data this is in onCreate

```
FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser ();
    String uid = mUser.getUid ();
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ( "data" ).child ( uid );
    myRef.keepSynced ( true );//for syncronize the firebase data
```

and the data is sent to firebase is like this,here is my java code for showing data from firebase to UI and my Application is Support Google and Facebook Signin,

```
  public void ShowData()
        {


            query1 = myRef.orderByChild ( "dateTime" ); 

            options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder < modelClass > ().setQuery ( query1 , modelClass.class ).build ();


            adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter < modelClass, MyVIewHolder > ( options )
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChanged() 
                {

                    super.onDataChanged ();
                }

                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyVIewHolder holder , final int position , @NonNull modelClass model) 
               {

                        holder.setFoodPost ( model ); //for set all data to view
```

this is open when the user doing long clik on data, here the delete window(alertDialog) open and delete the particulr data, but I want the delete window not open when other user want to delete other person data , means the user can delete only own data(delete alertDialog open when the user wants delete own data), if he wants delete other person data the delete window will not open so what should I do here ,and 
this code is also in onBilndViewHolder

```
     //for longPress on particular view

                    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener ( new View.OnLongClickListener () {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                            post_key = getRef ( position ).getKey ();

                                openDeleteWindow ();

                                 return true;
                            }

                        }
                    } );



                @NonNull
                @Override
                public MyVIewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent , int viewType) 
{
                    View v = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext () ).inflate ( 
                   R.layout.recycler_view_item_layout , parent , false );
                    Log.d ( "firee","orCreate" );
                    return new MyVIewHolder ( v );



                }
            };
            adapter.startListening (); //if you use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter then this is nessasry

            recyclerView.setAdapter ( adapter ); //set adapter into recyclerView
```

this is my firebase

```
 datamyapp-cbfba

    |-- data
        |-WNOAsWDaVlQXq2DssE9AsUCw1jB3    <- Device A (googleSignInKey)
        | |-M1UGU8pMJiNGd5zsG_r
        |   |-college:"ABES"
        |   |-contact:"956379797"
        |   |-dateTime:"03-03-2020 12:52:05"
        |   |-food: "Burger"
        |   |-name:"Vishal"
        |
        |-XiFNOWYYFHhjRdHx7AGOtchjN4x2   <- Device B (googleSignInKey)
          |-M1UGqWNjWVIlbtluD6D
           |-college:"TMU"
           |-contact:"9578379797"
           |-dateTime:"03-03-2020 12:50:05"
           |-food: "Pizza"
           |-name:"Ankit"
```

Answer (score 0):

For writing data into firebase you should write data separately for A & B. For reading data from firebase you can read all the data that has written by A or B. So for deleting you have no problem. Data are saved separated. A delete his/her data and B delete his/her data.

Comment: Sir,here is lots of user in application so i want the data is store by everone ,is showing by everyone but everyperson delete only own data not otherpersone data

Comment: No problem, as I said for reading you read all data which are written into database. For writing and deleting and updating every user have his/her accessibility to database. So I can't delete data of somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Just see this:

[image]

Here data of two users are saved ('keshtynejat' & 'mohammadmoeingolchin'). As you see data are saved completely separated. How do you read data of one user?! You can read data of all the users the same way.

Comment: thanku sir,but i have a confusion,sir here the data is not delete by other except owner of that data? ('keshtynejat' & 'mohammadmoeingolchin) delete only own data and read data of each other?

Comment: Yes, they can delete only own data. Of course you can give user access to all the data and every one can delete another one's data. All of that depends to your requirement.

Comment: no sir,tell me one thing sir, in your code, what will be the firebase  realtime database rule?

Comment: Sir how we create a diffrent child for diffrent user? sir i am new in android so i have lots of mistake soory sir.

Comment: and sir like yours in your code all data of the person is goes into person name chile and i have a diffrent UID for diffrent user and all the data goes into that user UID, and the rule is { "rules": { ".read": true, ".write": true } }  but the data is not showing to other user, go into my code and see the firebase database code , every person have diffrent uID and the data is goes in uID

Comment: See this videos of simplifiedcoding. They are useful for learning database. "https://www.dideo.ir/v/yt/I485b7LzYkM/"